# In Aframe, the target is not working for Light Spot

Tags: aframe

I want to point a spot light towards a specific object. According to documentation (https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/light.html)

[image]

there is an property target that takes the id of the object to point to. However target does not seem to react to any value.

`<a-light position="10 10 10" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" light="type:spot;color:#ff0000;intensity:100;distance:1000;decay:0.1;angle:3;penumbra:0; target:myplane"></a-light>`

Here is my codepen example:

https://codepen.io/jimver04/pen/JjZRJLz

- A-Frame Version: 1.3.0
- Platform / Device:  Windows 10, Firefox 106, Desktop 3080 RTX GPU
- Reproducible Code Snippet or URL: https://codepen.io/jimver04/pen/JjZRJLz

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it just needs a # before the plane id

`<a-light position="10 10 10" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" light="type:spot;color:#ff0000;intensity:100;distance:1000;decay:0.1;angle:3;penumbra:0;target:#myplane"></a-light>`

Comment: In general, It needs to be a valid [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)